# Is there a clearer way to visualize these data? [ggplot help]

Tags: r, ggplot2

Playing around with some CDC data looking to formulate a research question. I've been doing some basic statistics/analyses along with making some basic plots to better visualize the data.

One of the plots I created is here:
[image]

Is it possible to make this more clear (in the sense where we can better visualize the genuses by trap size and male mosquitoes counted)?

Here was my code:

```
ggplot(Hawaii.cdc, aes(MalesCollected, TrapType)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color=TrapSite, shape=Genus)) +theme_bw()
```

Here are my (randomly sampled) data:

```
> sampled_df<- sample_n(Hawaii.cdc, 50)
> dput(sampled_df)
structure(list(TrapType = c("BGS Trap", "BGS Trap", "BGS Trap", 
"BGS Trap", "BGS Trap", "BGS Trap", "BGS Trap", "BGS Trap", "BGS Trap", 
"BGS Trap", "BGS Trap", "BGS Trap", "BGS Trap", "BGS Trap", "Larval/Pupal Collection", 
"BGS Trap", "BGS Trap", "BGS Trap", "BGS Trap", "UV Light Trap", 
"BGS Trap", "BGS Trap", "BGS Trap", "BGS Trap", "BGS Trap", "BGS Trap", 
"BGS Trap", "BGS Trap", "BGS Trap", "BGS Trap", "BGS Trap", "BGS Trap", 
"BGS Trap", "BGS Trap", "BGS Trap", "BGS Trap", "BGS Trap", "UV Light Trap", 
"BGS Trap", "BGS Trap", "BGS Trap", "BGS Trap", "BGS Trap", "BGS Trap", 
"BGS Trap", "BGS Trap", "BGS Trap", "Larval/Pupal Collection", 
"BGS Trap", "BGS Trap"), AttractantsUsed = c("Lure", "Lure", 
"None", "Lure", "Lure", "Lure", "Lure", "Lure", "Lure", "Lure", 
"CO2 and Lure", "Lure", "Lure", "Lure and UV Led Light", "None", 
"CO2 and Lure", "Lure", "Lure", "Lure", "Lure", "CO2", "Lure", 
"None", "Lure", "CO2 and Lure", "Hay or grass infusion", "Lure", 
"Lure", "Lure", "Lure", "Lure", "Lure", "Lure", "Lure", "Lure", 
"Lure", "Lure", "BG", "Lure", "Lure", "Lure", "Lure", "Lure", 
"None", "Lure", "Lure", "Lure", "None", "CO2 and Lure and Led Uv Light", 
"Lure"), TrapID = c("Parking #1", "Air strip #4", "Parking #3", 
"#2", "#4", "Parking #2", "Air Strip #1", "Air strip #3", "Air strip #2", 
"Parking #4", "Air Strip #1", "Air Strip #1", "Parking #4", 
"Air strip #3", "0-6", "Baggage #1", "#4", "Parking #3", "Sewage #2", 
"Parking #1", "Sewage #3", "Baggage #4", "Air Strip #4", "Air strip #2", 
"Air Strip #4", "Air Strip #1", "Parking #3", "Air strip #2", 
"Air strip #4", "Air strip #1", "Parking #2", "#3", "Parking #2", 
"Parking #3", "Parking #1", "Parking #3", "Parking #1", "Air strip #1", 
"Air Strip #1", "Air Strip #1", "Parking #2", "Air strip #2", 
"#2", "Parking #3", "Air Strip #1", "Parking #2", "Air strip #4", 
"HOVE Container", "Parking #1", "Air Strip #3"), Latitude = c(19.71314, 
19.712502, 19.71311, 20.03724, 20.03977, 19.71312, 19.7121, 19.7124, 
19.71224, 19.71311, 19.711245, 19.711245, 19.71311, 19.712048, 
20.21925, 19.71502, 20.03977, 19.71311, 19.71238, 19.71314, 19.71239, 
19.715, 19.7125, 19.7125, 19.7125, 19.711245, 19.71311, 19.7125, 
19.7125, 19.71212, 19.71312, 20.03938, 19.71312, 19.71311, 19.71314, 
19.71311, 19.71314, 19.71212, 19.7121, 19.71212, 19.71312, 19.7125, 
20.03724, 19.71311, 19.71212, 19.71312, 19.7125, 19.088978, 19.71314, 
19.71224), Longitude = c(-155.0396, -155.057462, -155.03906, 
-155.82648, -155.83147, -155.03934, -155.05975, -155.05923, -155.05942, 
-155.03876, -155.059803, -155.059803, -155.03876, -155.057852, 
-155.75585, -155.04094, -155.83147, -155.03906, -155.03697, -155.0396, 
-155.03725, -155.04027, -155.05894, -155.05942, -155.05894, -155.059803, 
-155.03906, -155.05942, -155.05894, -155.05975, -155.03934, -155.82956, 
-155.03934, -155.03906, -155.0396, -155.03906, -155.0396, -155.05975, 
-155.05975, -155.05975, -155.03934, -155.05942, -155.82648, -155.03906, 
-155.05975, -155.03934, -155.05894, -155.762254, -155.0396, -155.05923
), Address = c("Kekuanaoa Street", "Airport Road", "Kekuanaoa Street", 
"Kawaihae Rd.", "Kawaihae Rd.", "Kekuanaoa Street", "Airport Road", 
"Airport Road", "Airport Rd.", "Kekuanaoa Street", "Airport Road", 
"Airport Road", "Kekuanaoa St.", "Airport Rd.", "Akoni Pule Hwy.Kohala", 
"Kukuanaoa Street", "Kawaihae Road", "Kekuanaoa Street", "Kekuanaoa Street", 
"Kekuanaoa St.", "Kekuanaoa St.", "Kekuanaoa St.", "Airport Road", 
"Airport Road", "Airport Road", "Airport Road", "Kekuanaoa Street", 
"Airport Road", "Airport Road", "Airport Road", "Kekuanaoa Street", 
"Kawaihae Rd.", "Kekuanaoa St.", "Kekuanaoa St.", "Kekuanaoa St.", 
"Kekuanaoa St.", "Kekuanaoa St.", "Airport Rd.", "Airport Road", 
"Airport Rd.", "Kekuanaoa Street", "Airport Road", "Kawaihae Rd.", 
"Kekuanaoa St.", "Airport Road", "Kekuanaoa Street", "Airport Road", 
"Keaka Blvd.", "Kekuanaoa Street", "Airport Road"), Town = c("Hilo", 
"Hilo", "Hilo", "Kawaihae", "Kawaihae", "Hilo", "Hilo", "Hilo", 
"Hilo", "Hilo", "Hilo", "Hilo", "Hilo", "Hilo", "Kohala", "Hilo", 
"Kawaihae", "Hilo", "Hilo", "Hilo", "Hilo", "Hilo", "Hilo", "Hilo", 
"Hilo", "Hilo", "Hilo", "Hilo", "Hilo", "Hilo", "Hilo", "Kawaihae", 
"Hilo", "Hilo", "Hilo", "Hilo", "Hilo", "Hilo", "Hilo", "Hilo", 
"Hilo", "Hilo", "Kawaihae", "Hilo", "Hilo", "Hilo", "Hilo", "Ocean View", 
"Hilo", "Hilo"), State = c("HI", "HI", "HI", "HI", "HI", "HI", 
"HI", "HI", "HI", "HI", "HI", "HI", "HI", "HI", "HI", "HI", "HI", 
"HI", "HI", "HI", "HI", "HI", "HI", "HI", "HI", "HI", "HI", "HI", 
"HI", "HI", "HI", "HI", "HI", "HI", "HI", "HI", "HI", "HI", "HI", 
"HI", "HI", "HI", "HI", "HI", "HI", "HI", "HI", "HI", "HI", "HI"
), County = c("Hawaii County", "Hawaii County", "Hawaii County", 
"Hawaii County", "Hawaii County", "Hawaii County", "Hawaii County", 
"Hawaii County", "Hawaii County", "Hawaii County", "Hawaii County", 
"Hawaii County", "Hawaii County", "Hawaii County", "Hawaii County", 
"Hawaii County", "Hawaii County", "Hawaii County", "Hawaii County", 
"Hawaii County", "Hawaii County", "Hawaii County", "Hawaii County", 
"Hawaii County", "Hawaii County", "Hawaii County", "Hawaii County", 
"Hawaii County", "Hawaii County", "Hawaii County", "Hawaii County", 
"Hawaii County", "Hawaii County", "Hawaii County", "Hawaii County", 
"Hawaii County", "Hawaii County", "Hawaii County", "Hawaii County", 
"Hawaii County", "Hawaii County", "Hawaii County", "Hawaii County", 
"Hawaii County", "Hawaii County", "Hawaii County", "Hawaii County", 
"Hawaii County", "Hawaii County", "Hawaii County"), TrapSite = c("Airport", 
"Airport", "Airport", "Business", "Business", "Airport", "Airport", 
"Airport", "Business", "Airport", "Airport", "Airport", "Business", 
"Airport", "Residential", "Airport", "Business", "Airport", "Airport", 
"Airport", "Business", "Airport", "Airport", "Airport", "Airport", 
"Airport", "Airport", "Airport", "Airport", "Airport", "Airport", 
"Business", "Business", "Business", "Business", "Business", "Airport", 
"Airport", "Airport", "Business", "Airport", "Airport", "Business", 
"Business", "Airport", "Airport", "Airport", "Residential", "Airport", 
"Airport"), TrapSet = c("05/23/2017", "01/06/2020", "09/25/2017", 
"08/29/2017", "07/04/2017", "02/05/2018", "01/28/2019", "04/02/2018", 
"12/10/2018", "03/09/2020", "07/29/2019", "03/25/2019", "12/16/2018", 
"01/21/2020", "07/12/2017", "06/21/2017", "11/20/2017", "06/06/2017", 
"06/19/2017", "12/19/2017", "06/21/2017", "08/07/2017", "06/19/2017", 
"08/27/2018", "06/22/2017", "07/08/2019", "06/25/2018", "04/02/2018", 
"09/03/2018", "03/12/2018", "10/29/2018", "07/12/2017", "01/21/2019", 
"01/14/2019", "01/07/2019", "12/10/2018", "09/06/2017", "12/06/2017", 
"12/03/2018", "07/10/2017", "07/09/2018", "07/02/2018", "06/13/2017", 
"06/21/2017", "07/26/2017", "10/16/2017", "10/01/2018", "10/17/2017", 
"09/16/2019", "11/26/2018"), SetTimeOfDay = c("Morning", "Morning", 
"Morning", "Afternoon", "Afternoon", "Morning", "Morning", "Morning", 
"Morning", "Morning", "Morning", "Morning", "Morning", "Morning", 
"Afternoon", "Morning", "Morning", "Morning", "Morning", "Afternoon", 
"Afternoon", "Afternoon", "Morning", "Morning", "Morning", "Morning", 
"Morning", "Morning", "Morning", "Morning", "Morning", "Afternoon", 
"Morning", "Morning", "Morning", "Morning", "Afternoon", "Afternoon", 
"Morning", "Afternoon", "Morning", "Morning", "Afternoon", "Afternoon", 
"Morning", "Morning", "Morning", "Afternoon", "Morning", "Morning"
), TrapCollect = c("05/25/2017", "01/10/2020", "09/26/2017", 
"08/31/2017", "07/05/2017", "02/08/2018", "02/04/2019", "04/06/2018", 
"12/14/2018", "03/13/2020", "08/02/2019", "03/29/2019", "12/20/2018", 
"01/24/2020", "07/12/2017", "06/22/2017", "11/22/2017", "06/08/2017", 
"06/20/2017", "12/20/2017", "06/22/2017", "08/09/2017", "06/20/2017", 
"08/31/2018", "06/23/2017", "07/12/2019", "06/29/2018", "04/06/2018", 
"09/07/2018", "03/16/2018", "11/02/2018", "07/14/2017", "01/28/2019", 
"01/18/2019", "01/14/2019", "12/14/2018", "09/08/2017", "12/07/2017", 
"12/07/2018", "07/11/2017", "07/13/2018", "07/06/2018", "06/15/2017", 
"06/22/2017", "07/28/2017", "10/20/2017", "10/05/2018", "10/17/2017", 
"09/20/2019", "11/30/2018"), CollectTimeOfDay = c("Morning", 
"Morning", "Morning", "Afternoon", "Afternoon", "Morning", "Morning", 
"Morning", "Morning", "Morning", "Morning", "Morning", "Morning", 
"Morning", "Afternoon", "Morning", "Morning", "Morning", "Morning", 
"Afternoon", "Afternoon", "Afternoon", "Morning", "Morning", 
"Morning", "Morning", "Morning", "Morning", "Morning", "Morning", 
"Morning", "Afternoon", "Morning", "Morning", "Morning", "Morning", 
"Afternoon", "Afternoon", "Morning", "Afternoon", "Morning", 
"Morning", "Afternoon", "Afternoon", "Morning", "Morning", "Morning", 
"Afternoon", "Morning", "Morning"), Genus = c("Aedes", "Aedes", 
"Aedes", "Aedes", "Aedes", "Culex", "Culex", "Culex", "Aedes", 
"Aedes", "Aedes", "Aedes", "Aedes", "Aedes", "Aedes", "Aedes", 
"Aedes", "Aedes", "Aedes", "Aedes", "Culex", "Culex", "Aedes", 
"Aedes", "Culex", "Culex", "Aedes", "Culex", "Culex", "Culex", 
"Aedes", "Aedes", "Aedes", "Culex", "Aedes", "Aedes", "Culex", 
"Culex", "Aedes", "Aedes", "Aedes", "Aedes", "Aedes", "Aedes", 
"Aedes", "Aedes", "Aedes", "Aedes", "Aedes", "Aedes"), Species = c("albopictus", 
"albopictus", "albopictus", "aegypti", "albopictus", "quinquefasciatus", 
"quinquefasciatus", "quinquefasciatus", "albopictus", "albopictus", 
"albopictus", "albopictus", "albopictus", "albopictus", "albopictus", 
"albopictus", "aegypti", "albopictus", "albopictus", "vexans", 
"quinquefasciatus", "quinquefasciatus", "albopictus", "albopictus", 
"quinquefasciatus", "quinquefasciatus", "albopictus", "quinquefasciatus", 
"quinquefasciatus", "quinquefasciatus", "albopictus", "aegypti", 
"albopictus", "quinquefasciatus", "albopictus", "albopictus", 
"quinquefasciatus", "quinquefasciatus", "albopictus", "albopictus", 
"albopictus", "albopictus", "albopictus", "albopictus", "albopictus", 
"albopictus", "albopictus", "aegypti", "albopictus", "albopictus"
), LifeStage = c("Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", 
"Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", 
"Adult", "Adult", "Larvae/pupae", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", 
"Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", 
"Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", 
"Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", 
"Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", 
"Adult", "Larvae/pupae", "Adult", "Adult"), EggsCollected = c("No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", "No"), LarvaeCollected = c("No", "No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
"No", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
"No", "No", "Yes", "No", "No"), PupaeCollected = c("No", "No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
"No", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
"No", "No", "Yes", "No", "No"), FemalesCollected = c(32, 1, 10, 
5, 1, 7, 2, 4, 3, 7, 33, 19, 0, 8, 15, 1, 2, 8, 1, 3, 12, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 10, 2, 15, 1, 18, 2, 29, 2, 3, 1, 9, 3, 6, 
5, 4, 2, 0, 4, 6, 1, 22, 2), MalesCollected = c(54, 0, 9, 3, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 5, 2, 0, 12, 0, 15, 4, 0, 2, 0, 0, 5, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 3, 0, 6, 0, 0, 1, 4, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 
1, 3, 0, 5, 0), UnknownCollected = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
), ReportDate = c("08/01/2017 8:31 PM", "05/07/2020 4:13 PM", 
"04/19/2018 8:44 PM", "04/19/2018 8:44 PM", "08/01/2017 8:31 PM", 
"01/31/2019 8:05 PM", "07/30/2019 9:38 PM", "10/05/2018 9:15 PM", 
"07/30/2019 9:38 PM", "05/07/2020 4:13 PM", "05/07/2020 4:13 PM", 
"05/07/2020 4:13 PM", "07/30/2019 9:38 PM", "05/07/2020 4:13 PM", 
"04/19/2018 8:44 PM", "08/01/2017 8:31 PM", "04/19/2018 8:44 PM", 
"08/01/2017 8:31 PM", "08/01/2017 8:31 PM", "04/19/2018 8:44 PM", 
"08/01/2017 8:31 PM", "04/19/2018 8:44 PM", "08/01/2017 8:31 PM", 
"10/05/2018 9:15 PM", "08/01/2017 8:31 PM", "05/07/2020 4:13 PM", 
"10/05/2018 9:15 PM", "10/05/2018 9:15 PM", "10/05/2018 9:15 PM", 
"10/05/2018 9:15 PM", "01/31/2019 8:45 PM", "08/01/2017 8:31 PM", 
"07/30/2019 9:38 PM", "07/30/2019 9:38 PM", "07/30/2019 9:38 PM", 
"07/30/2019 9:38 PM", "04/19/2018 8:44 PM", "04/19/2018 8:44 PM", 
"07/30/2019 9:38 PM", "08/01/2017 8:31 PM", "01/31/2019 8:22 PM", 
"10/05/2018 9:15 PM", "08/01/2017 8:31 PM", "08/01/2017 8:31 PM", 
"04/19/2018 8:44 PM", "04/19/2018 8:44 PM", "11/20/2018 7:37 PM", 
"04/19/2018 8:44 PM", "05/07/2020 4:13 PM", "07/30/2019 9:38 PM"
)), row.names = c(NA, -50L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(
    TrapType = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), AttractantsUsed = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), TrapID = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Latitude = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), Longitude = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), Address = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Town = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), State = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), County = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), TrapSite = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), TrapSet = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), SetTimeOfDay = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), TrapCollect = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), CollectTimeOfDay = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Genus = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Species = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), LifeStage = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), EggsCollected = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), LarvaeCollected = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), PupaeCollected = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), FemalesCollected = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), MalesCollected = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), UnknownCollected = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), ReportDate = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), delim = ","), class = "col_spec"), problems = <pointer: 0x600002e98b20>, class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: check https://clauswilke.com/dataviz/ for some great intro/ideas on visualisation.

Comment: This seems like a question of opinion, but my suggestions would be 1) Don't use color to show 13 categories -- it's hard to reliably distinguish more than about 10 different colors; maybe better to use facets for that variable. 2) There's a lot of overplotting which makes it hard to distinguish shapes and colors -- geom_jitter might be better here. 3) Often useful to sort by something meaningful (e.g. # malesCollected) using factors (e.g. `%>% mutate(TrapType = forcats::fct_reorder(TrapType, MalesCollected))`)  instead of just using alphabetical ordering.

Comment: The "clearest" visualization depends on what you want to show. You're showing 4 different variables here, seemingly trying to answer the question "How effective is each trap type against which genus in which location?" which might be useful for EDA to get a sense for some patterns, but it won't be good for communication, since it shows many simultaneous messages, none clearly. Figure out a narrower question or observation and tailor your visualization to make that point. e.g. "Most trap sites were in airports" or "Ovicup traps caught more Culex mosquitoes than UV light traps."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my suggestion:

1. Change the axis
2. Transform y to log
3. Use `position_jitter`

```
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(Hawaii.cdc, aes(y=log(MalesCollected), x=TrapType)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color=TrapSite, shape = Genus), 
           position = position_jitter(width=0.2, height=0.5), size = 2) +
  ylab("Males Collected")+
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What about something like a heat map:

```r
tmp <- sampled_df %>% 
  group_by(TrapType, TrapSite, Genus) %>% 
  summarise(n = sum(MalesCollected)) %>% 
  group_by(Genus) %>% 
  mutate(pct = n/sum(n))

ggplot(tmp, aes(x=TrapSite, y=TrapType, fill=pct)) + 
  geom_tile(col="white") + 
  facet_wrap(~Genus, ncol=1) + 
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(panel.grid=element_blank())
```

[image]